# Loading PostCSS "postcss-normalize" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'postcss-normalize'

Tags: yarnpkg, postcss

node v16.16.0
yarn 1.22.19

After package upgrade and loading my react app, i got this error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Loading PostCSS "postcss-normalize" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'postcss-normalize'
Require stack:
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

(@/Users/nnn/1work/app-ui/src/index.css)
```

But i can search in the folder

```
$ find node_modules  -name 'postcss-normalize'
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/postcss-normalize
```

The package.json looks like this (after deleted our private packages)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "2.2.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto": "npm:crypto-browserify",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "framer-motion": "10.16.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "9.1.3",
    "sass": "1.66.1",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "web-vitals": "3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.4.3",
    "husky": "8.0.3",
    "jest-junit": "16.0.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "14.0.1",
    "prettier": "3.0.2"
  }
```

Did search online, no this exact error. Similar one suggested to upgrade node version but doesn't work for me.
Any suggestions pls ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The reason for the error is that postcss needs to find postcss-normalize relative to itself, and in my monorepo project postcss was hoisted to the root of the project, but postcss-normalize wasn't.

```bash
> find -iname 'postcss' -type d
./node_modules/postcss

> find -iname 'postcss-normalize' -type d
./frontends/projectA/node_modules/postcss-normalize
./frontends/projectB/node_modules/postcss-normalize
./frontends/projectC/node_modules/postcss-normalize
```

That's weird because all three projects depend upon the same version.  I couldn't find an easy way to get postcss-normalize hoisted to the root of the project.  In the end I deleted the lock file (yarn.lock / package-lock.json) and regenerated it.

That's a gross solution, because it means all the sub-dependencies can change (and all the potential bugs that brings), but it's the best I could figure out.

Comment: I had a similar issue with postcss-scss for linting and in the end throwing away my lock-file resolved the issue, thanx for the hint!